# gedit: Reading C code

Tags: gedit

How can you trace function calls, DEFINEs and declarations in a complex project from the listed includes in a given file using gedit?

In other IDEs you usually right-click on a function or variable and it can take you to its original declaration.

Comment: `gedit` is a text editor, not an IDE.  Consider using something like Anjuta if you want an IDE.

Comment: I really love gedit because it feels so light-weight. Is there no way to still do it in gedit?

Comment: There might be something specifically for this, but then you'll want something else later... meanwhile, consider that the reason `gedit` is so much faster than an IDE is specifically that it is *not* an IDE.  Features like that have a performance cost.

Answer (score 0):

Gedit is an extremely light text editor and not an IDE. Therefore to answer you,

It is not possible to do what you are asking in Gedit. It never "reads" your code per se (IDEs/compliers do this) and hence can't locate function definitions etc.